# xamarin forms text to speak

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms

We have a Xamarin Forms app that is implementing text to speak using this cross-platform plugin:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/TextToSpeechPlugin.

The plugin works great for two of our iPads (both iPad Air 2), however it won't work on an iPad 4th Gen. By using HockeyApp and other debugging methods, we have found out that the speech method is being called on the 4th Gen iPad but the sound isn't working. We also made sure that silent mode is disabled and sound is working for other apps.

Has anybody else run into a similar issue and have any ideas on what might be going on?

Thanks!